# substitute variables for liquibase property files with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
mvn -X resources:resources liquibase:diff -Psit
```

In my pom file, I have the following:

```
 <profiles>
        <!-- These have been added to support running liquibase commands via maven. -->
        <!-- Filters are used to substitute values in the liquibase.properties file. -->
        <!-- Example: mvn -X resources:resources liquibase:generateChangeLog -Pnft -Dliquibase.password=<your-pwd> -Dliquibase.username=<your-user> -->
        <profile>
            <id>sit</id>
            <build>
                <filters>
                    <filter>src/main/resources/application-sit.properties</filter>
                </filters>
            </build>
        </profile>
      ...
   </profiles>
```

And my liquibase property file looks like the following:

```
changeLogFile: ${spring.liquibase.change-log}
driver: ${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}
url: ${spring.datasource.url}
username: ${spring.datasource.username}
password: ${spring.datasource.password}
verbose: true
```

I am getting an error from running this command which reports it can't resolve any of the variables I have defined ie ${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}

I've looked at some examples and checked the docs, which gives the impression that what I am trying do to is possible, I just can't get it to run. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe there are more of those folks on the Liquibase (https://forum.liquibase.org/)or Springboot forum (https://coderanch.com/f/96/Spring)?  Could you share the documentation that lead you to think this was possible?

Comment: Thanks @ronak, I'll take it up with the liquibase team, but I don't think they maintain the maven plugin itself, I'll double check that and post the solution if I get one! Seems strange though that I can get it to work with -Dspring.datasource.password but if I put it in a spring profile i.e application-dev.properties it doesn't resolve them.